# Tensorflow-io for Apple M1

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1

I have an Apple M1 chip. For a project I need an environment with Python 3.8.3, Tensorflow 2.4.1 and Tensorflow-io 0.17.1. Python and Tensorflow already work. I installed Python with Rosetta 2 and pyenv and compiled Tensorflow from source. So far I haven't found a suitable solution for tensorflow-io.
'python3 setup.py -q bdist_wheel' didn't worked

Comment: Have you tried using `!pip install wheel` and `!pip install tensorflow-io`?

Comment: In what way did it not work? What kind of error did you get?